# Nodejs Https get Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I'm trying to get a `filtered` record from `loopback`, but I don't understand why `nodejs` gives error on fallowing commands:

```
const https = require('https');
    var uid = '02644da038b37d7ba70b7ee1a92ba1d9';
        var URL = 'https://mobileapp.mydomain.com/api/uuids?filter[where][uuid]='+uid;
https.get(URL, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);    
  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error('ERROR:',e);
});
```

the error on output:

```
ERROR: { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mobileapp.mydomain.com mobileapp.mydomain.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'mobileapp.mydomain.com',
  host: 'mobileapp.mydomain.com',
  port: 443 }
```

Comment: It can't resolve the hostname `mobileapp.mydomain.com` into an IP-address.

Comment: I don t know why but `nslookup` resolve subdomain and shows static `ipaddres`

Comment: Are you using some sort of antivirus or firewalling software that may block DNS lookups from Node?

Comment: No there is no any antivirus or firewall it is win 2008 based VPS.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously the domain you used is not valid.

Comment: when I put URL `https://mobileapp.mydomain.com/api/uuids?filter[where][uuid]=02644da038b37d7ba70b7ee1a92ba1d9` the result is a `json`.

Comment: Have a look at you `hosts` file, I think you're mis-pointing `mobileapp.mydomain.com` to a specific IP address, which can not be recognized on the internet.

Comment: Can I use request method?

Comment: I tried to `ping mobileapp.mydomain.com`, it cannot be recognized, see if your shell output something contains `[127.0.0.1]`?

Comment: I have static IP address of my domain and subdomain. I was using node 6.3.1 and upgrade to 8.5.0 and now looks ok.

Answer (score 3):

URL shouldn't contain https://
modify url 
from
`var URL = 'https://mobileapp.mydomain.com/api/uuids?filter[where][uuid]='+uid;` 
 to `var URL = 'mobileapp.mydomain.com/api/uuids?filter[where][uuid]='+uid;`

I had this issue and this resolved it.

Comment: It really helped me, The error was gone.
ERROR: { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mobileapp.mydomain.com mobileapp.mydomain.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'mobileapp.mydomain.com',
  host: 'mobileapp.mydomain.com',
  port: 443 }

Answer (score 1):

probably it's because of SSL authentication in loopback, can you please try this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-ssl)